# Can't use differrent EditorTemplates for the same DateTime value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, mvc-editor-templates

Let's say in my model I have `public DateTime Date {get;set;}` property. On the view it should be represented in a couple of textboxes - one for the Date and another for the Time.

I created two different editor templates

DateTime.cshtml:

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "datePicker", style = "width:90px"  })
```

and TimeOnly.cshtml

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortTimeString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "timePicker", style = "width:90px" })
```

And the EditorFor fields on the View

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date,"TimeOnly")
```

---

Now, the problem is that the actual value of Date property passed to the controller comes with default time 12:00.
The same thing happens to the Date if we change the order of the EditorFor fields - the Date rolls back to default Date value immediately after TimeOnly template has applied, although the Time part of it stays correct.

Again on the view itself the values are ok, but on submit it passes default value to the controller, either with correct Date and default Time and vice versa (it depends which template used first)

Of course I can always separate Date and Time just by adding another property to the model, but is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Hanselman blogged about how a [custom model binder](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx) could be used in this case.

Comment: now I'm gonna say that: Darin, I don't believe you are an actual living person. It can't be. I think you are a bot created in collaboration of several smartest people on the planet who probably work for Google. It's impossible to always come out with correct answers so fast. You're freaking me out.

Comment: @Agzam, I am just using my experience to aggregate the vast sea of information scattered over the internet into StackOverflow :-) This is to say, I have gone through most of the questions asked here in my previous projects so the answers are just obvious.